# How to create many powerpoint presentations containing a slide with a variable from an Excel table?

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am trying create PowerPoint presentations using values in an Excel table.

A2, A3, A4, etc. will each contain a name. The slide in each pptx file will be a test containing three paragraphs, and at the beginning the names in those cells are addressed in this way:

> Dear 'BA2',
>
> [paragraph1 ]
>
> [paragraph 2]
>
> Yours faithfully,
> ...

And same goes for the other cells.

```
Dim ppApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim ppPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dm ppSlide As PowerPoint.Slide

Set ppApp = New PowerPoint.Application

ppApp.Visible = True
ppApp.Activate

Set ppPres = ppApp.Presentations.Add 

Set ppSlide = ppPres.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutBlank)

Set ppApp = New PowerPoint.Application

ppApp.Visible = True
ppApp.Activate

set ppSlide = ppPres.Slides.Add(2,pp LayoutBlank(
ppSlide.Select

Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy
ppSlide.Shapes.Paste
```

This code will copy and paste the whole table into one slide. Quite different from what I want, but what I need to know is how to just paste these cell by cell, into separate sheets, using a for loop or something of that sort.

Comment: First of all, lets be on the same page about terminology: do you want a separate "presentation" for each correspondence or do you want to have a single presentation with separate "slides" for each correspondence? Secondly, are we dealing with tables here (and if so why?) or can this not be achieved by having a simple TextBox object in each slide, containing the correspondence name and the 2 paragraphs?

Comment: Hello thanks for the response. Separate presentation for each, just the first slide for now is what I'm trying to figure out. And at this point no tables also but later on there will be slides which contain charts and other values in the same way (I guess learning how to make it work with textboxes would solve my problem then too though).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Goto master slide view and make a template as you need; like specific text boxes and things, then from excel make a new slide of that template each time and fill those boxes from variables which are in the cell. If you are just learning to program it'll be better than trying to add text boxes and everything by code.
The code on the for loop depends on your presentation slide structure, if you can specify the data and format, then it is clear.
Put this code in powerpoint VBA, it'll let you access the data in excel, open the excel sheet with data and run it after you put something appropriate in the loop.

```
Public Sub test()
Dim excelSht As Worksheet
Dim excelApp As Excel.Application
Set excelApp = GetObject(, "excel.application")
Set excelSht = excelApp.ActiveSheet
Dim path As String
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Show
    path = .SelectedItems(1)
End With
'Set rng = excelApp.Selection ' use this if you want to select the data in advance
Set rng = excelSht.Range("A2:A140") ' use this if your data range is fixed
For Each cel In rng
    For Each shp In Application.Presentations(1).Slides(1).Shapes
        If shp.Name Like "Title 1" Then shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Dear, " & cel.Value ' this one choose the name of the shape of which one you want to change the text.
    Next
    Application.Presentations(1).SaveAs (path & "\" & cel.Value & ".pptx")
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: That sounds like an amazing way to approach it. Could you please help me a little further?

Let's say I have already made some master slides. How do I then save this as a template and use it for the purpose of applying this solution?

So imagine all the page is constant, and I just use one textbox at the right spot to paste this variable from the cells A2 all the way down to A140 for example (I made a mistake regarding this in the question which I will fix now).

And each of these going into a separate powerpoint file, as they are prepared for the different addressees.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: So basically you have one powerpoint already prepared but need 139 of those with just one name different? everything else remaining the same? or do you also need to make the first powerpoint from the excel data itself?

Comment: Let's say one PowerPoint is already made!

So at later points based on the values in the other cells I would like to also add to each of these powerpoints different things.

For now I have the template already prepared, 1 slide with a text that remains constant, and just 1 textbox that has the different variables from A2 to A140. How would I paste these variables into the different files so they each contain a letter addressed to the recipient based on the Excel sheet?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I have edited the answer to include sample code, you can modify which text box you want your data to be inserted into. It'll save as the file as different name into a folder you select, should satisfy your need.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response! I appreciate it very much. This already gives me some really cool ideas and introduces important concepts and tricks I had no idea about. However, unfortunately, there is an issue. Could you help me out a bit further? It says Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set; For the line that says Set Rng = ...
What could be the problem?

And I must name the text box Title 1 for this to work?

Comment: Is your excel sheet open? you have to open the sheet and run the code in the powerpoint for it to work, and also check if `excelSht` is not empty/null.  As for the "Title 1" it was the default name of the title box i was trying this on, you need to input your name there, if you aren't sure you can use `like "Title*"` if you want to modify the title (will modify all title boxes). you can try adding `Debug.print shp.Name` in the loop outside the condition to first get the list of all shape names and then choose which one you want.

Comment: Man, you're amazing. Thank you so much! This is so cool. So another question... I really want to learn how to build up on this and do other things. This was only the start. Is there a good resource that you know of which can help me out with this? Would you be okay with helping me out with this also? I suppose I will need to do that in new threads.

Comment: yeah, you are right now at the best resource site, search what you need to know, just need to be careful of wording and you'll find most answers. Normally I just google what I don't know and I find answers. (Little secret : it was my first time automating powerpoint, i have done a lot of vba in excel and word but I wasn't familiar with powerpoint object model.) just keep seeking answers to your problem and you'll learn as you solve more.

Comment: Thank you very very much for all the time and energy you put into helping me out with this. I'll definitely be doing that. Wish you an awesome day.

Comment: Hey there, would there be any chance of getting in touch with you to work out some more VBA issues if your time allows and you're up for it? Thanks man!